# Parsing a string into a double

Tags: beginner, c, parsing, floating-point

I'm trying to understand the `strtod()` function, and how I can handle any user input given to the function. I assume I tested for everything, however I am hoping for a review to make sure and to catch anything I missed. (I know I should separate everything into functions, however, I am just trying to understand the nature of the function, therefore I left everything in `main`.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

/*@param MAXSIZE max number of chars that are converted to a 64bit double*/
#define MAXSIZE 1077 

int main() {

    char str[MAXSIZE];
    printf("Enter a rational number: ");

    for (;;) {
        if (fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin) != NULL) {
            if (strchr(str, '\n')) {
                str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0';
            }
            if (str[0] != '\0') {
                break;
            }
            printf("\nTry again: ");
        }
    }

    char* endptr = NULL;
    errno = 0;
    double number = strtod(str, &endptr);

    //passes over trailing whitespace
    for (; isspace(*endptr); ++endptr);

    if (errno == ERANGE) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error out of range...\n");
    }
    else if (*endptr != '\0') {
        fprintf(stderr, "error could not convert: %s\n", str);
    }
    else {
        printf("Your string was converted into the rational number: %lf\n", number);
    }
    printf("Your string was: %s\n", str);
    printf("Press any key to continue...\n");
    getch();
}
```

Comment: BTW, asking the user to enter a "rational" number might lead them to think they can type `1/3` here.  "Decimal" may be a better choice. (not an answer, as it's tangential to the requested review)

Comment: @Toby Speight, I agree completely, thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0';` is an overkill. `fgets` reads (at most) one string, that is there is at most one `'\n'` in the buffer, and `strchr` will return its position. Consider

```
    char * newline = strchr(str, '\n');
    if (!newline) {
        .... // handle input too long condition
    } else if (newline == str) {
        .... // handle empty input condition
    } 
    *newline = '\0';
    break;
```

Notice that even `newline = '\0'` is redundant: `'\n'` *is* a whitespace.

---

Do not invent error messages. This is what `strerror` and `perror` are for. Also keep in mind that `strtod` *may* set `errno` to errors other than `ERANGE` (some implementations use `EINVAL` as well). Consider

```
    if (errno != 0) {
        perror("strtod");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! So if errno is not zero, it is some error value and perror will return what error occured?

Comment: I also have another question, perror(errno) does not compile, however perror(NULL) works as expected, was that a typo or am I missing something? Another thing, can I still use my fprintf() statement? It works fine, I know i'm customizing my own error message but is there a reason I shouldn't? If yes how else could I implement it? Thank you!

Comment: @chris360 `perror` will print the standard error message. `strerror` will _return_ an error message, so you may chose to print it in a more fancy manner. Also yes, there was a typo, sorry.

Comment: How is `str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0';` overkill?  Certainly a popular answer to [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221/2410359).  Should it be 2-3 times slower than `strchr()` method, that time savings is certainly swamped by the `fgets()` itself.  Also lack of `'\n'` in `if (!newline) {` is caused by 2 other reasons too beside "input too long": prior embedded null character and end-of-file occurring.  True about no need to drop the `'\n'` as `for (; isspace(*endptr); ++endptr);` will handle that.

Answer (score 1):

1. With `strtod()`, `if (errno == ERANGE) {` is problematic.

When the input string represents a value exceeding +/- `DBL_MAX`, `errno == ERANGE` is set - no problem there.

When the input string represents a tiny non-zero value `-DBL_MIN < x < DBL_MIN`, `errno == ERANGE` **might** be set.  It is implementation-defined.

> If the result underflows ..., the functions return a value whose magnitude is no greater than the smallest normalized positive number in the return type; whether `errno` acquires the value `ERANGE` is implementation-defined. C11 §7.22.1.3 10

These is no truly robust solution.  The best is to not flag an error when the answer is tiny.

```
if (errno == ERANGE) {
  if (number >= -DBL_MIN && number <= DBL_MIN) {
    errno = 0;
  }
}
```

2. Printing a `double` using `"%f"` does not well present large numbers nor tiny ones.  Suggest `"%e"` or `"%g"`
3. `1077` is not the max number of `char` that are converted to a 64bit double.  There is no C specified upper bound.  Although `1077` is certainly  generous, buffer size needed to print `-DBL_TRUE_MIN` is 1077 + 1 and so would need 1077 + 1 (`\n`) + 1 (`\0`) to read with `fgets()` for IEEE binary64.

IAC, the buffer size needed is not the number of character used to *print* a double into a string, but the number of characters needed when reading.  Depending on coding goals, this could be as small as about 400 (extras characters will not *likely* make a difference) or pedantically: unlimited.

4. `str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0';` is sufficient.

   ```
   // if (strchr(str, '\n')) {
   //   str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0';
   // }
   str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0';
   ```
5. OP's code fails to detect input of all spaces because "passes over trailing whitespace" may be passing over *leading* white-spaces.

   ```
   double number = strtod(str, &endptr);
   // add
   if (str == endptr) fail();
   ```

---

I'll offer a more robust "parsing a string into a double" code that allows leading/trailing whitespace taking into account the above §7.22.1.3 10 spec.

```
// return true on success
bool string_double(const char * restrict str, double * restrict dest) {
  if (str == NULL) return false; // Optional NULL check
  errno = 0;
  char *endptr;
  double y = strtod(str, &endptr);
  if (errno == ERANGE) {
    if (fabs(y) > 1.0) {
      // Alternatives for handling overflow exist, 
      // it depends on coding goals.
      // Go for simply for now.
      return false; // overflow
    }
    // Let all underflow pass as code can't portably detect it.
    // Code has no real portable options. C11 §7.22.1.3 10
    // Suggest `y = 0.0` for highest portability
    // Otherwise leave `y` as is for most informative.
    y = 0.0;  // Optional
  } else if (errno) {
    // Should some other errno occur, 
    // (no other errno value are specified in the standard for strod()),
    // consider returning.
    return false;  
  }

  if (str == endptr) return false;  // no conversion, e.g. all spaces

  // consume trailing white-space
  while (isspace((unsigned char) *endptr)) endptr++;
  if (*endptr) return false; // trailing junk

  if (dest) *dest = y;
  return true;
}
```